# Confusion Regarding a Change of Variables by $r=e^{t}$ and the Multivariate Chain Rule

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule, change-of-variable

I have been attempting to perform a change of variables on the radial component of a PDE. We assume (by ansatz) that $f(r)$ is a function that admits at least two derivatives.

Taking a change of variables $r = e^{t}$ with $r_t = e^t = r$ and $t_r = r^{-1}$, we may write the multivariate chain rule for the first derivative as $f_t = f_r r_t = r f_r$. My confusion stems from taking the second derivative to determine a formula for $f_{tt}$. I my first method, I write that

$$(r f_r)_r = f_{tr}$$
$$r f_{rr} + f_r = f_{tt} t_r = f_{tt} r^{-1}$$
yielding
$$f_{tt} = r^2 f_{rr} + r f_r$$

I believe that this approach is correct as it directly quotes definitions and does not employ any special properties. For the second method, I try to commute the partial derivatives of $f$ to provide what I had hoped would be a more intuitive derivation.

$$
\begin{align}
f_{tt} &= (f_r r)_{t} = f_{rt} r + f_r r_t = f_{rt} r + f_r r \\
       &= f_{tr} r + f_r r = (f_r r)_r r + f_r r = r^2 f_{rr} + 2 r f_r
\end{align}
$$

I believe that the second $r f_r$ term arises from an unjustifiable equivalency $f_{rt} = f_{tr}$. I might also have been careless with my notation and that could have concealed a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that the second $r f_r$ term arises from an unjustifiable equivalency $f_{rt} = f_{tr}$.

Indeed.  The indices commute when they are *independent* variables, **but** $r$ is dependent on $t$.

So don't do that.  Instead, just apply the chain rule again.  $(f_r)_t=(f_r)_r~r_t$

$\qquad\begin{align}f_{tt} &= f_{rt}r+f_r r\\&=f_{rr}r_t~r+f_rr\\&=f_{rr}r^2+f_rr\end{align}$

Comment: You have taught a valuable lesson about diminishing marginal returns. I tried to pull an all-nighter but ended up playing the fool. Thank you again